# NameError: name 'uname' is not defined : PYTHON WITH LINUX

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81JUz.jpg)Dear All,
I am trying to execute the below code in python3.6 environment, but when ever i run the code getting error  as below:

File "pysys_func2.py", line 11, in 
    print ("Gathering system information with %s command:\n" %uname)
NameError: name 'uname' is not defined

Comment: It's just a matter of indentation

Answer (score 0):

Because of using python3.6 and  indentation, then it should be :

```
import subprocess


def uname_func():
        uname = "uname"
        uname_arg = "-a"
        print ("Thong tin %s ",uname)

        subprocess.call([uname, uname_arg])
```